# when link is clicked, find if parent with certain child exists jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, parent-child

What I'm looking for, is a way to determine whether or not the parent of the clicked link,  with a class of `row-fluid` contains an id matching a predetermined child.

what I have tried so far is [Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/RZPW2/11/) (jsFiddle)

Can anyone please explain why my code does not work? And also, my coding is pretty terrible, so any advice on shorthand code is fine. I tend to over-think things often

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="success-1">Entry One</div>
    <div class="span3"> <a href="#" id="1" class="delete-me">delete</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="accord-2">Entry Two</div>
    <div class="span3"> <a href="#" id="2" class="delete-me">delete</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="success-3">Entry Three</div>
    <div class="span3"> <a href="#" id="3" class="delete-me">delete</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.delete-me').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($(this).parent(".row-fluid").has("#accord-*")) {
        var name = $("#accord-" + id).html();
        alert(name);
    }else{
        var name = $("#success-" + id).html();
        alert(name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work - only the condition in the `if` has been changed:

```
$('.delete-me').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($(this).closest(".row-fluid").has("[id^='accord-']").length > 0) {
        var name = $("#accord-" + id).html();
        alert(name);
    }else{
        var name = $("#success-" + id).html();
        alert(name);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RZPW2/15/

The main problem with your `if` condition:

```
if($(this).parent(".row-fluid").has("#accord-*")) {
```

...is that it is always truthy, because the `.has()` method returns a jQuery object not a boolean, and any object is truthy.

Also, the `.parent()` method only gets the immediate parent element, which in the anchor's case is not the `.row-fluid` element - use `.closest()` instead to go up to the closest ancestor with that class.

Finally, to select by an `id` that starts with a particular string use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

If each group is always going to contain either the `accord-*` or `success-*` element you could instead give both of those a common class:

```
<div id="success-1" class="entryName">Entry One</div>
```

...because then you wouldn't need the `if` test at all:

```
$('.delete-me').on('click', function () {
    var name = $(this).closest(".row-fluid").find(".entryName").html();
    alert(name);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RZPW2/18/

Comment: thanks for the in-depth analysis, it's right up my street. I guess I was naive to think the `attribute starts with` selector could be as easy as an `*`. Things are so simple nowadays. I think I will go for the class of `entryName` also. Simplify FTW!!

Answer (score 2):

Couple of issues with your code:

1. `$(this).parent(".row-fluid")` won't work because the row is not the immediate parent of your link, you should use `closest(".row-fluid")` to traverse up and find the first parent that matches the selector
2. You can't use wildcards in your selectors like in `has("#accord-*")`, you need to use the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector: `"[id^='accord-']"`, also `has()` returns a jQuery object, not a boolean
3. Not a real issue but you should use data attributes to comply with HTML5 standards `<a href="#" data-id="3" class="delete-me">delete</a>`

And if you want to simplify things a bit, you could write

```
$('.delete-me').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    alert($(this).closest('.row-fluid').find('#success-'+id+',#accord-'+id).text());
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZPW2/12/)**

Comment: Thanks a bunch man! Now I see where I am going wrong. I had the HTML5 in mind too. Although, I'm not sure I may change that. Does the same job anyhow. And the short version is great!

Comment: Regarding html5 standards, the existing html is already compliant isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm not 100% on this, but I think it has to do with accessing the proper parent from which to traverse the `DOM` and grab the proper `DIV`. If that will always be the structure of your `DIV`'s, then you can go about it like so:

```
$(".delete-me").on("click", function () {
    var obj = $(this), id = obj.attr("id"), parent = obj.parent().parent(), name = parent.find("div[id$='-" + id + "']").html();
    alert(name);
});
```

Which uses the [ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) (`id$=`), or since that is the only `DIV` with an `ID` in the tree, you could use [has attribute](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) like so:

```
$(".delete-me").on("click", function () {
    var obj = $(this), parent = obj.parent().parent(), name = parent.find("div[id]").html();
    alert(name);
});
```